# How do I pull only the rows where the values are in the 1980s and 1990s?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently working in Pandas on python and I was wondering how to pull the values listed above from this dataframe.  They will be used to create a new dataframe called data1_CBS_80s_90s.  For reference I also attached a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your data as text, not images. Use `data1_CBS.head(30).to_dict()` and paste it here

Comment: Well, can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you whether the value is "in the 80s or 90s"? Is the value actually a number, or is it a string?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: upper bound modified from 1990 to 1999. Thanks @mozway for the comment.

EDIT: given the column `Year` is of type int.
If it is of type `str` then you need to convert it first.

Not sure if the following is what you want.

```
data1_CBS_80s_90s = data1_CBS[data1_CBS['Year'].between(1980, 1999)]
```

Comment: I think the upper bound is 2000, not 1990 ;)

Comment: @mozway Oh I think you are right, I will edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to [@Yu-Sheng Li's probably best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68961699/16343464), **if the column type is string** you can match with a regex:

```
data1_CBS_80s_90s = data1_CBS[data1_CBS['Year'].str.match('19[89].')]
```